# Unity Parse SDK Login Fail Exception 404

Tags: exception, sdk, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm using the Unity Parse SDK for a login system. Everything works fine if the login information is correct, if its incorrect then it causes a exception which causes a conflict with my Prime31 Etcetera Alert popup. The exception doesn't appear to cause any other problems, the app runs fine otherwise.

Exception:

```
System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.

-----------------

Parse.ParseException: 404: not found

  at Parse.ParseClient+<>c__DisplayClass8.<RequestAsync>b__7 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1`2[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.String],System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c__DisplayClass3`1+<>c__DisplayClass5[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].<ContinueWith>b__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I tried to catch the exception using

```
catch( System.AggregateException e )
```

and

```
catch( System.Exception e )
```

but neither seems to catch it.

I have a temporary work around to use Etcetera by delaying its activation by one frame. However this isn't a perfect solution, there is the possibility that a one frame offset can still fail.

How can I correctly catch this exception or otherwise handle/avoid it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to catch the exception, check if the Task is faulted:

```
Task t = ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, password);
while (!t.IsCompleted)
    yield return null;

if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
{
   // the exception can be found in t.Exception
}
else
{
    // login successful
}
```

As for getting more information about your current 404 exception, you're unfortunately out of luck. Parse doesn't provide any more info in Unity, apparently due to Unity's limited HTTP stack. More info here: https://www.parse.com/questions/unity-sdk-handling-errors